# Combining VBA code for Outlook/excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have two separate codes that I need to work as one. I've gotten the first to work, but I'm making a mistake when trying to add the second part. How do I get the second part added in to the first code? The first code is exporting the body of emails from a folder into excel. The second part is supposed to break out parts of the body into it's own cell.

```
Sub ExportMessagesToExcel()
Dim olkMsg As Object, _
    excApp As Object, _
    excWkb As Object, _
    excWks As Object, _
    intRow As Integer, _
    intVersion As Integer, _
    strFilename As String
strFilename = InputBox("Enter a filename (including path) to save the exported messages to.", "Export Messages to Excel")
If strFilename <> "" Then
    intVersion = GetOutlookVersion()
    Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet
    'Write Excel Column Headers
    With excWks
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Subject"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Received"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Sender"
    End With
    intRow = 2
    'Write messages to spreadsheet
    For Each olkMsg In Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
        'Only export messages, not receipts or appointment requests, etc.
        If olkMsg.Class = olMail Then
            'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export
            excWks.Cells(intRow, 1) = olkMsg.Subject
            excWks.Cells(intRow, 2) = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
            excWks.Cells(intRow, 3) = GetSMTPAddress(olkMsg, intVersion)
            intRow = intRow + 1
        End If
    Next
    Set olkMsg = Nothing
    excWkb.SaveAs strFilename
    excWkb.Close
End If
Set excWks = Nothing
Set excWkb = Nothing
Set excApp = Nothing
MsgBox "Process complete.  A total of " & intRow - 2 & " messages were exported.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Export messages to Excel"
    End Sub

Private Function GetSMTPAddress(Item As Outlook.MailItem, intOutlookVersion As Integer) As String
Dim olkSnd As Outlook.AddressEntry, olkEnt As Object
On Error Resume Next
Select Case intOutlookVersion
    Case Is < 14
        If Item.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
            GetSMTPAddress = SMTP2007(Item)
        Else
            GetSMTPAddress = Item.SenderEmailAddress
        End If
    Case Else
        Set olkSnd = Item.Sender
        If olkSnd.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
            Set olkEnt = olkSnd.GetExchangeUser
            GetSMTPAddress = olkEnt.PrimarySmtpAddress
        Else
            GetSMTPAddress = Item.SenderEmailAddress
        End If
End Select
On Error GoTo 0
Set olkPrp = Nothing
Set olkSnd = Nothing
Set olkEnt = Nothing
 End Function

Function GetOutlookVersion() As Integer
Dim arrVer As Variant
arrVer = Split(Outlook.VERSION, ".")
GetOutlookVersion = arrVer(0)
 End Function

 Function SMTP2007(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
On Error Resume Next
Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
SMTP2007 = olkPA.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001E")
On Error GoTo 0
Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

The part I need to add in is:

```
    Select 
    Range("B2").Formula = "=MID(Trim(Clean(A2)),FIND(""Risk Owner:"",Trim(Clean(A2)))+13,FIND(""Counterparty:"",Trim(Clean(A2)))-FIND(""Risk Owner:"",Trim(Clean(A2)))-13)" 
Range("C2").Formula = "=MID(Trim(Clean(A2)),FIND(""Counterparty:"",Trim(Clean(A2)))+15,FIND(""Trade ID:"",Trim(Clean(A2)))-FIND(""Counterparty:"",Trim(Clean(A2)))-15)" 
Range("D2").Formula = "=MID(TRIM(CLEAN(A2)),FIND(""Trade ID:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))+11,FIND(""Fee Leg ID:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-FIND(""Trade ID:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-11)" 
Range("E2").Formula = "=MID(TRIM(CLEAN(A2)),FIND(""Fee Leg ID:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))+13,FIND(""Termination Method:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-FIND(""Fee Leg ID:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-13)" 
Range("F2").Formula = "=MID(TRIM(CLEAN(A2)),FIND(""Termination Method:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))+21,FIND(""Termination amount:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-FIND(""Termination Method:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-21)" 
Range("G2").Formula = "=MID(TRIM(CLEAN(A2)),FIND(""Termination amount:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))+21,FIND(""Expected Recovery:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-FIND(""Termination amount:"",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-21)" 


 'Copy formulas
Sheets("Import").Select 
Range("B2").Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & LastUsedRow), Type:=xlFillDefault 
Range("C2").Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & LastUsedRow), Type:=xlFillDefault 
Range("D2").Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & LastUsedRow), Type:=xlFillDefault 
Range("E2").Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & LastUsedRow), Type:=xlFillDefault 
Range("F2").Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & LastUsedRow), Type:=xlFillDefault 
Range("G2").Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & LastUsedRow), Type:=xlFillDefault 


 'Paste values to remove formulas
Sheets(Array("Import")).Select 
Sheets("Import").Activate 
Cells.Select 
Selection.Copy 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Added 3/13

```
    Sub ExportMessagesToExcel()
    Dim olkMsg As Object, _
        excApp As Object, _
        excWkb As Object, _
        excWks As Object, _
        intRow As Integer, _
        intVersion As Integer, _
        strBuffer As String, _
        strFilename As String, _
        strTemp As String, _
        arrLines As Variant, _
        varLine As Variant, _
        bolComments As Boolean
    strFilename = InputBox("Enter a filename (including path) to save the exported messages to.", MACRO_NAME)
    If strFilename <> "" Then
        intVersion = GetOutlookVersion()
        Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()
        Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet
        'Write Excel Column Headers
        With excWks
            .Cells(1, 1) = "Transaction Type:"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "Select One:"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "Area"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "Store"
            .Cells(1, 5) = "Date"
            .Cells(1, 6) = "Iar Date"
            .Cells(1, 7) = "Name of submitter"
            .Cells(1, 8) = "Key Rec"
            .Cells(1, 9) = "Issue"
            .Cells(1, 10) = "Vendor #"
            .Cells(1, 11) = "Vendor address"
        End With
        intRow = 2
        'Write messages to spreadsheet
        For Each olkMsg In Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
            'Only export messages, not receipts or appointment requests, etc.
            If olkMsg.Class = olMail Then
                'Add a row for each field in the message you want to export
                strBuffer = ""
                bolComments = False
                arrLines = Split(olkMsg.Body, vbCrLf)
                For Each varLine In arrLines
                    strTemp = Trim(varLine)
                    If bolComments Then
                    Else
                        If Left(strTemp, 17) = "Transaction Type: " Then
                            excWks.Cells(intRow, 4) = Mid(strTemp, 17)
                        Else
                            If Left(strTemp, 14) = "Select one: " Then
                                excWks.Cells(intRow, 5) = Mid(strTemp, 16)
                            Else
                                If Left(strTemp, 5) = "Area: " Then
                                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 6) = Mid(strTemp, 5)
                                Else
                                    If Left(strTemp, 8) = "Store #: " Then
                                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 7) = Mid(strTemp, 8)
                                    Else
                                        If Left(strTemp, 16) = "Date MM/DD/YYYY: " Then
                                             excWks.Cells(intRow, 8) = Mid(strTemp, 16)
                                       Else
                                        If Left(strTemp, 28) = "IAR Week End Date MM/DD/YYYY: " Then
                                             excWks.Cells(intRow, 9) = Mid(strTemp, 28)
                                          Else
                                            If Left(strTemp, 44) = "Name Title of Person Submitting Issue Sheet: " Then
                                                excWks.Cells(intRow, 10) = Mid(strTemp, 14)
                                            Else
                                                If Left(strTemp, 29) = "Keyrec#: " Then
                                                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 11) = Mid(strTemp, 29)
                                                Else
                                                    If Left(strTemp, 32) = "Detailed Description of Issue: " Then
                                                        excWks.Cells(intRow, 12) = Mid(strTemp, 32)
                                                    Else
                                                        If Left(strTemp, 9) = "Vendor #:" Then
                                                            bolComments = True
                                                        End If
                                                    End If
                                                End If
                                            End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                Next
                 excWks.Cells(intRow, 10) = strBuffer
                intRow = intRow + 1
            End If
        Next
        Set olkMsg = Nothing
        excWkb.SaveAs strFilename
        excWkb.Close
    End If
    Set excWks = Nothing
    Set excWkb = Nothing
    Set excApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Process complete."
End Sub
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting and where in the code are you getting the error?

Comment: and where in your code do you want to add Part 2 - in it's own procedure, in an existing procedure?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the code after **End Select** and leav off the word 'Select'

What I mean is, try this

```
...
End Select

Range("B2").Formula = "=M ....
```

and **NOT:**

```
...
End Select
Select 
Range("B2").Formula = "=MID( ...
```

HTH

Philip

Comment: Thanks that worked... well it worked to get the code to run. The out put still isn't what I thought it would be. I thought that second part would take the body and break it into cells and provide the values in between the key words in the formulas.

Comment: that's related to your formulas isn't it - I suspect that you need to past the values in column A then debug the formulas in columns B, C and so on...

Comment: Post some example of what column A would be then I can help you debug the formulas

Comment: So you're saying you tested the formulas right in excel with out running a message export through VBA? I did that too. The formula did nothing for me. I'm lost :(

Comment: well, I tested the formulas in Excel - I did that by pasting this string 'aaaaabbbbcccc Risk Owner: This is The Risk Owner xxxx Counterparty: This is the CounterParty baby hhh ggg Trade ID: vvvv TRADE ID bbbjjjj' in Cell A1, and the formula in B1 produced this result: This is The Risk Owner xxxx

Comment: in order for the formulas to work, you need something in column A

Comment: I put a copy of the same data that would be exported from outlook in col A. This is the data that would contain the key words for extracting data?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I posted at the same time you were posting.  Thanks for the info. It just appears I'm having formula problems and not VBA issues. I tried your example as well and it didn't work. Must be a bad setting somewhere.

Comment: I got this to work, but the problem is it's to basic. It didn't go all the way back to Risk owner: and it gave part of the Counterparty header. The problem is I never know how many characters the answer may be. =MID(A1, SEARCH("Risk Owner: ",A1) + LEN("Counterparty: "), 30)

Comment: Well, this works _=MID(TRIM(CLEAN(A2)),FIND("Risk Owner:",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))+12,FIND("Counterparty:",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-FIND("Risk Owner:",TRIM(CLEAN(A2)))-13)_ if you have **aaaaabbbbcccc Risk Owner: This is The Risk Owner Counterparty: This is the CounterParty baby hhh ggg Trade ID: vvvv TRADE ID bbbjjjj** in Cell A2

Comment: I did get it to work. The code has ""Risk Owner"" where as in excel directly it worked as "Risk owner". Should the " be in there twice on the code? I think I may also have some compatablity issues. The information that the VBA spits out from Outlook has questions marks in a box around all the fields. Even the correct formula won't work on that sheet.

Comment: Update: I've got the formula working. My data required a =clean formula first, which i don't understand since clean is in the larger formula. I also thought the formula would only capture the excat wording between the set headers, but it's grabbing part of header. In the end I need to get all these steps in the code.

Comment: well you can tweak the numbers in the code to extract different strings... BTW, you could also do the extraction in code using VBA instr and Mid functions

Comment: I tired that :) (added code above). It only worked on one column and gave the wrong answer. I've got the other formulas working now. I just need to figure out how to get into the code the formula to clean column a, then run these formulas we've been working on on the clean results. Thanks for all your help so far.